# Create JSON Data from CSV

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a CSV file with following data: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX7B2.png)
I am using pandas with python.

I would like to have the JSON data as follows:

```
{    
       "VMName": "vm101", 
       "tags": [
        {"scope": "Environment", "tag": "Production"}, 
        {"scope": "Application", "tag": "App1"}, 
        {"scope": "Tier", "tag": "Web"}
        ]
       "VMName": "vm102", 
       "tags": [
        {"scope": "Environment", "tag": "Production"}, 
        {"scope": "Application", "tag": "App1"}, 
        {"scope": "Tier", "tag": "App"}
        ]
       "VMName": "vm103", 
       "tags": [
        {"scope": "Environment", "tag": "Production"}, 
        {"scope": "Application", "tag": "App1"}, 
        {"scope": "Tier", "tag": "DB"}
        ]
       "VMName": "vm104", 
       "tags": [
        {"scope": "Environment", "tag": "UAT"}, 
        {"scope": "Application", "tag": "App1"}, 
        {"scope": "Tier", "tag": "Web"}
        ]
       "VMName": "vm105", 
       "tags": [
        {"scope": "Environment", "tag": "UAT"}, 
        {"scope": "Application", "tag": "App1"}
        ]
       "VMName": "vm106", 
       "tags": [
        {"scope": "Environment", "tag": "UAT"}, 
        {"scope": "Application", "tag": "App1"}, 
        {"scope": "Tier", "tag": "DB"}
        ]
}
```

How can achieve this using Pandas

Comment: Please don't provide the sample data as image. Provide it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your **expected JSON is not valid**, if you need the valid JSON from the CSV, you can do it this way without using `pandas`

```
import csv
import json

csv_file = open('data.csv', 'r')
json_file = open('data.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("Name", "Environment", "Application", "Tier")
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames)

vm_list = []
for row in reader:
    if row["Name"] != "Name":  # skip the header row
        vm = {}
        vm["VMName"] = row["Name"]
        vm["tags"] = [
            {"scope": "Environment", "tag": row["Environment"]},
            {"scope": "Application", "tag": row["Application"]}
        ]
        if row["Tier"]:
            vm["tags"].append({"scope": "Tier", "tag": row["Tier"]})
        vm_list.append(vm)

json.dump(vm_list, json_file, indent=4)

csv_file.close()
json_file.close()
```

## data.csv

```
Name,Environment,Application,Tier
vm101,Production,App1,Web
vm102,Production,App1,App
vm103,Production,App1,DB
vm104,UAT,App1,Web
vm105,UAT,App1,
vm106,UAT,App1,DB
```

## data.json

```
[
  {
    "VMName": "vm101",
    "tags": [
      {
        "scope": "Environment",
        "tag": "Production"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Application",
        "tag": "App1"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Tier",
        "tag": "Web"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "VMName": "vm102",
    "tags": [
      {
        "scope": "Environment",
        "tag": "Production"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Application",
        "tag": "App1"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Tier",
        "tag": "App"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "VMName": "vm103",
    "tags": [
      {
        "scope": "Environment",
        "tag": "Production"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Application",
        "tag": "App1"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Tier",
        "tag": "DB"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "VMName": "vm104",
    "tags": [
      {
        "scope": "Environment",
        "tag": "UAT"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Application",
        "tag": "App1"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Tier",
        "tag": "Web"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "VMName": "vm105",
    "tags": [
      {
        "scope": "Environment",
        "tag": "UAT"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Application",
        "tag": "App1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "VMName": "vm106",
    "tags": [
      {
        "scope": "Environment",
        "tag": "UAT"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Application",
        "tag": "App1"
      },
      {
        "scope": "Tier",
        "tag": "DB"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```